# Print file content in JavaScript (implicity pass file path not use input browser box)

Tags: javascript, file, filereader

I have this code below which prints a file content to the log. This works fine.

Now, I want to do the same but instead of getting the file from input browse box, I want to write it implicitly like:

```
var file = 'c:\\1.txt';
```

How can I do so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Log Printer in Javascript
    </title>

    <input type="file" id="fileinput"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printFileToLog(evt) {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
                console.log(this.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        };

        document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', printFileToLog, false);
    </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.

You can't just read any file from user's computer unless they explicitly allow you to do it.

Comment: what is the best workaround to solve this? I have a txt file and I need to read its content and do some manipulations on it. I am working with javascript and I want it to be automaticly not with input browser box...

Comment: @Matoy The best workaround is to use the code you already have. You can't read a file without file input.

Comment: Thanks. and if this file sits on the web on some url...?

Comment: @Matoy Then you can just load it with Ajax.